# Select Details of every student's latest purchase with just 1 query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 tables like in this picture:

[image: pic]

I want to find details of every student's latest purchase in SQL Server with just 1  query. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Latest? You need a timestamp column too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that "latest" means "biggest `id`", a simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from shoptbl s
where s.id = (select max(s2.id) from shoptbl s2 where s2.name = s.name);
```

Your data model is messed up.  You have a perfectly good numeric id for each student.  There is no need to repeat the `name` in other tables.  Use the `id` instead.